# Scala 2.9: Parsers subclass not recognizing "Elem" override?

Tags: scala, parser-combinators

I wrote a parser to act as a lexer.  This lexer parses a file and returns a list of tokens, each of which is a case class or object that extends a common trait.

I am now trying to write a parser for the output of the lexer, but I have hit a very confusing snag.  The parser is happy to implicitly cast my case objects, but throws a fit if I even try to call `apply(classHere)` manually.

The following is a simplified version of my code:

```
// CODE
trait Token

case class StringWrapperIgnoresCase(val string: String) {
  private case class InnerWrapper(s: String)

  lazy val lower = string.toLowerCase

  override lazy val hashCode = InnerWrapper(lower).hashCode

  override def equals(that: Any) =
    that.isInstanceOf[StringWrapperIgnoresCase] &&
      lower == that.asInstanceOf[StringWrapperIgnoresCase].lower
}

case class ID(val text: String)
  extends StringWrapperIgnoresCase(text)
  with Token {
    override def toString = "ID(" + text + ")"
  }

case object PERIOD extends Token

object Parser extends Parsers {
  type Elem = Token

  def doesWork: Parser[Token] = PERIOD

  def doesNotWork: Parser[Token] = ID
}
```

The compiler reports the following message about `doesNotWork`:

```
// ERROR MESSAGE
type mismatch;  found   : alan.parser.ID.type (with underlying type object alan.parser.ID)  required: alan.parser.Parser.Parser[alan.parser.Token]
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: It wasn't clear to me from your question exactly what you were asking, but now that you've specified that you want a parser that matches any `ID` in your answer, here's a more idiomatic solution:

```
val id: Parser[ID] = accept("ID", { case i: ID => i })
```

Here you've provided a description of what the parser wants (for error messages) and a partial function with `ID`s as its domain. You could also use the `acceptIf` version that xiefei provides in a comment on your answer.

---

When you refer to a case class (as opposed to a case object) without a parameter list, you get the automatically generated companion object, which is *not* an instance of the class itself. Consider the following:

```
sealed trait Foo
case class Bar(i: Int) extends Foo
case object Baz extends Foo
```

Now `Baz: Foo` is just fine, but `Bar: Foo` will give an error very similar to what you're seeing.

Note also that what's happening here isn't strictly *casting*. The `Parsers` trait has a method with the following signature:

```
implicit def accept(e: Elem): Parser[Elem]
```

When you write this:

```
def doesWork: Parser[Token] = PERIOD
```

You're trying to type an `Elem` as a `Parser[Elem]`, and the implicit conversion kicks in (see section 7.3 of [the spec](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf) for more information about implicit conversions). When you write this, on the other hand:

```
def doesNotWork: Parser[Token] = ID
```

You're trying to type the `ID` companion object (which has type `ID.type`, not `ID` or `Token`, and therefore not `Elem`) as a `Parser[Elem]`, and there's no implicit conversion that makes this possible.

You're probably better off writing out `accept(PERIOD)` and `accept(ID("whatever"))`, for now, at least, and obeying the deprecation warning that says the following when you try to compile your code:

> Case-to-case inheritance has potentially dangerous bugs which are
>   unlikely to be fixed.

Comment: drstevens, you deleted your answer before I could ask you a question.  Why shouldn't I inherit from case classes?  I have to admit, the thread you linked confused me >_>

Answer (score 0):

Using what TravisBrown and drstevens have said, I have added a new production to the parser:

```
def id = {
  acceptIf(
    _ match {
      case ID(_) => true
      case _ => false
    }
  )("'ID(_)' expected but " + _ + " found")
}

def nowWorks = id
```

I won't accept this as the answer for the time being to allow someone to provide a more elegant solution than this.  This looks a bit messy for my tastes, and I'm certain someone more accustomed to the functional programming approach will turn this into an elegant one-liner.

Comment: `acceptIf(ID.unapply(_).isDefined)(...)`. And you should accept Travis Browns answer. It pointed out the problem in your code at language level and suggested the solution. You did not mention the logic (which shows up in this one) you actually want in your question and should not expect others to be mind readers.

Comment: Tried that after seeing the post, but that doesn't compile.  I may still accept Travis Brown's answer, but I don't think I expected mind-reading of anyone.  I said that my Parser was accepting "the output of the lexer", and showed a couple examples of Token cases it returns.  Hard-coding values for ID the way Travis did means that the Parser can only match that one ID!

Comment: It looks like `acceptMatch` would work better than `acceptIf` here. Take a look at it on in [Scaladoc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/parsing/combinator/syntactical/TokenParsers.html). It takes a partial function instead of a predicate, and if the partial function is defined for the input it returns the result.